# Summing a List of BigIntegers using streams in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, biginteger

I have a `List<BigInteger>` and I want to sum its contents. It can be easily done by looping through it.

```
 List<BigInteger> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
  //Some code that populates listOfNumbers
  ... 
  BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("0");
  for(BigInteger num : listOfNumbers) {
        sum = sum.add(num);
  }
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do it using `Java 8` streams.

Comment: you could try something like 
listOfNumbers.stream().map(BigDecimal::doubleValue).sum().map(BigDecimal:valueOf), but your solution is more optimal

Comment: @BorislavStoilov The list contains BigInteger elements not BigDecimal elements.

Comment: @sank Isn’t the technique exactly the same for both `BigXx` types?

Comment: `BigInteger sum = listOfNumbers.stream()
                .reduce(BigInteger::add)
                .get();`

Comment: `listOfNumbers.stream() .reduce(BigInteger::add) .orElse(BigInteger.ZERO)`